# Getting error 'Could not register new connection at TOSCAAutomationService.Reason: Connection Timeout of 15000 ms has been exceeded!" in Tosca

Tags: automation, tosca

I am new to TOSCA. When i tried to run my test case in TOSCA 13.0 version i am getting  error 'Could not register new connection at TOSCAAutomationService.Reason: Connection Timeout of 15000 ms has been exceeded!.'
Please kindly help since i have registered for certification course and also my trail version of TOSCA will expire after few days.Hope for a reply.

Answer (score 0):

a bit late of a reply but I was running into the same issue and the only thing worked for me was a complete uninstall and then reinstall of tosca.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting up the ToscaAutomationServices in Task scheduler.
Go to TaskManager->Services tab->ToscaAutomationServices->Right click->Start.